# Converting a time to GMT based on the spreadsheet's timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I need to convert a string into GMT based on the spreadsheet's timezone. People may be using my sheet around the world so the spreadsheet's timezone is not static.

The user inputs something like `2:20 PM`. If the user is in GMT-5, I want it to spit out `7:20 PM`.

I was thinking something like this but I have no clue how to turn the string into a datetime object using the variable `zone`:

```html
function test(){

var time = "2:20 PM"

var zone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

 var adjustedTime = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", HHmm)

Logger.log(adjustedTime);

}
```

Comment: Add 5 hours to get to GMT

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 2:20pm GMT-5 is equivalent to 7:20pm GMT-0, so there isn't always a need to convert the time zone.

Comment: @Cooper that only works for my timezone. It might be used by people in various timezones.

Comment: @Diego I want the 2:20PM string to be changed to 7:20PM (if the spreadsheet is in GMT-5).

Comment: @Cooper It has to do it itself based on the spreadsheet's timezone. I can't go into everyone's spreadsheet and change the formula for them. I edited the question. Perhaps it is clearer now.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you shoujld do the research yourself and figure out the code on your own.  We're not a free script writing service.  We try to answer scripting questions so your need to provide a [mcve] which means figure it out and write your own code and if you have problems with the code then return for help.

Comment: @Cooper There is a minimal reproducible example and I'm clear about what doesn't work in the code.  See this line above, "I have no clue how to turn the string into a datetime object using the variable zone:". I've done lots of research on this btw.

Comment: @Cooper If you don't know how to fix it, that's fine. But I literally have no idea how to turn a string into a datetime object. Any answer I found has a solution that they refer to as "timezone-naive" which doesn't help me. Keep in mind I have taught myself appsscript. It may seem chincy but it is supposed to be minimal. I cut out all the irrelevant code which is quite complex (at least for my low skill-level).

Comment: [The answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't turn a string into a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using a variable time zone if you don't also have a date. When you use Google's [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) method, Google will attempt to do this automatically for you, but will give you a weird value because [how we record time has changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Ecuador). You can check (I set my spreadsheet and script to the "America/Guayaquil" time zone like yours):

```
function timeAsSeenByGoogle() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1"); // 2:20 PM
  console.log(range.getValue()); // Sat Dec 30 1899 14:20:00 GMT-0514 (Ecuador Time)
                                 // Note the time zone of GMT-0514
}
```

The biggest issue for you is that you have users in multiple time zones using the same spreadsheet. **You need a way to know which time zone the user is in.**

I suggest adding another field with a dropdown so they can select their time zone. Then you can combine those fields to create a new [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using the current day (?) as a reference. You'll have to use [`getDisplayValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) to prevent Google from reading the time value as a date, and then parse your strings to come up with the appropriate times.

Otherwise, you could create a modal or sidebar that uses client-side code to get the user's actual time zone.

If instead you just need to get the current time, then simply use an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to record the time.

Comment: Thanks so much. Moving towards a user inputed timezone made things so much easier. I ended up having them input it as GMT -/+ __. Then grabbed the input and did a simple setFormula as "=A1 & " + timeVariable + "/24" where A1 is the GMT time.